# parse csv - not recognized file

Tags: vb.net

Just want to get confirmation. We got parser for csv files. We received yesterday file which not look like on csv file (comma separated or fixed). There is no unified separator as , or . or tab . The guy who sent that wrote that: "The Node file is not going to be in a comma separated format, nor will the field separations be uniform". So its not comma separated/or fixed file, its just some custom file am i right?

format:

```
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02<SPACE>cpsModuleModel<SPACE>9152<SPACE>1<DOUBLESPACE>cpsmM100
```

example:

```
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02 cpsModuleModel 9152 1  cpsmM100 
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02 cpsModuleModel 9152 2  cpsDblWide 
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02 cpsModuleModel 9152 3  cpsEmpty 
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02 cpsModuleModel 9152 4  cpsEmpty 
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02 cpsModuleModel 9152 5  cpsEmpty 
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02 cpsModuleModel 9152 6  cfetf205 
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02 cpsModuleModel 9152 7  cettf100 
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02 cpsModuleModel 9152 8  cpsEmpty 
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02 cpsModuleModel 9152 9  cettf100 
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02 cpsModuleModel 9152 10  cpsEmpty 
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02 cpsModuleModel 9152 11  cpsEmpty 
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02 cpsModuleModel 9152 12  cpsEmpty 
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02 cpsModuleModel 9152 13  cpsEmpty 
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02 cpsModuleModel 9152 14  cpsEmpty 
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02 cpsModuleModel 9152 15  cpsEmpty 
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02 cpsModuleModel 9152 16  cpsEmpty 
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02 cpsModuleModel 9152 17  cpsEmpty 
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02 cpsModuleModel 9152 18  cpsEmpty 
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02 cpsModuleModel 9152 125  cpsmp100 
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02 cpsModuleModel 9152 126  cpsmp100 
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02 cpsModuleModel 9152 127  cpsEmpty 
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02 cpsModuleModel 9152 128  cpsEmpty 
AL-MCR01 cpsModuleModel 86209 1  cpsmM100 
AL-MCR01 cpsModuleModel 86209 2  cpsDblWide 
AL-MCR01 cpsModuleModel 86209 3  cfbrm105 
AL-MCR01 cpsModuleModel 86209 4  cfbrm105 
AL-MCR01 cpsModuleModel 86209 5  cfbrm105 
AL-MCR01 cpsModuleModel 86209 6  cfbrm105 
AL-MCR01 cpsModuleModel 86209 7  cfbrm105 
AL-MCR01 cpsModuleModel 86209 8  cfbrm105
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is a little troubling: `"nor will the field separations be uniform"`.  Hopefully that refers to the doublespace, not file to file.  Since it isnt uniform though, I think that would qualify it as a custom format, though not too exotic.

If you think you can take what "the guy" said as a contract that the file will look like that, there are 2 other ways to parse it without resorting to TextFieldParser. Both are pretty easy.

```
AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02<SPACE>cpsModuleModel<SPACE>9152<SPACE>1<DOUBLESPACE>cpsmM100
```

#### Use OleDB and a Schema to import it

Due to the space delimiter you cant take maximum advantage of the Schema, for instance naming the columns.  Create a `Schema.Ini` in the same folder as the data file and add the following definition block:

```
[MCRData.csv]
ColNameHeader=false
CharacterSet=ANSI
Format=Delimited( )
DecimalSymbol=.
CurrencySymbol=$
```

Unfortunately, the double space in the file will create an extra column and as posted each line has a trailing space with creates another.  That may be an artifact of HTML/post format etc.  The `Format` entry is a single space, since that may not be clear.

The code is simple:

```
Dim csvStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\Temp;Extended Properties='TEXT'"
Dim csvSQL = "SELECT * FROM MCRData.csv"

Using csvCn = New OleDbConnection(csvStr),
         cmd As New OleDbCommand(csvSQL, csvCn)

    Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        myDT = New DataTable
        da.Fill(myDT)
    End Using

    dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = True
    dgv.DataSource = myDT
End Using
```

[image]

As I said you cant define the columns since the delimiter is not uniform, so they default to F1, F2 etc.  F5 is an artifact of the doublespace and F7 from th trailing space.

#### String Split

Usually `String.Split` on am actual CSV is not a very good idea because the comma can be a legitimate character in one of the fields, especially as a currency decimal.

In this case, with a space delimiter it seems unlikely the source would also have a space in the data; `AAP-MCR01-to-MCR02` seems to indicate s/he is aware of that. `String.Split` also allows a little clean up:

```
myDT = New DataTable
'ToDo: use better names, may retype some
myDT.Columns.Add("Col1", GetType(String))
myDT.Columns.Add("Col2", GetType(String))
myDT.Columns.Add("Col3", GetType(String))
myDT.Columns.Add("Col4", GetType(String))
myDT.Columns.Add("Col5", GetType(String))

Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Temp\MCRData.CSV")
Dim parts As String()
Dim cells As Int32() = {0, 1, 2, 3, 5}

For Each line As String In lines
    ' trim any trailing spaces, cvt dbl space to single
    line = line.Trim.Replace("  ", " ")

    parts = line.Split(" "c)
    If parts.Length = 5 Then
        Dim dr As DataRow = myDT.NewRow

        ' ToDo: conversions
        dr.Item(0) = parts(0)
        dr.Item(1) = parts(1)
        dr.Item(2) = parts(2)
        dr.Item(3) = parts(3)
        dr.Item(4) = parts(4)

        myDT.Rows.Add(dr)
    End If
Next
```

The `dr.Item(0) = parts(0)` assignments could be done in a loop, I left it out since you may way to convert one or two values to numbers.  The result is a little cleaner:

[image]

---

The VB `TextFieldParser` will work well too.  It ends up being almost the exact same amount of code as the `String.Split()` method.  It will create a 6th faux column due to the trailing space which may not even exist in the real file.

It will handle multiple delimiters, but you want to set them as:

```
Using parser As New TextFieldParser("C:\Temp\MCRData.CSV")
    parser.Delimiters = New String() {"  ", " "}
```

Specify the doublespace first, then a space.  It chops the text in the order given, so if you specify space first, you will end up with the empty Col5 as with OleDb.

The `DataTable` and `DataGridView` are just an easy way to visualize the result.

### Reformat the file to a standard CSV

`The problem is i got already huge solution for lot diffrent files not only .csv`

In that case, it would be pretty simple to change the file into a standard CSV:

```
Dim inFile As String = "C:\Temp\MCRData.CSV"
Dim outFile As String = "C:\Temp\MCRData.XSV"

Using sr As New StreamReader(inFile)
    Using sw As New StreamWriter(outFile, False)
        Dim line As String
        Do Until sr.EndOfStream
            line = sr.ReadLine

            ' replace doublespace with space
            ' then space with comma
            line = line.Trim.Replace("  ", " ").Replace(" ", ",")
            sw.WriteLine(line)
        Loop
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: thank you for diffrent way of parse it. The problem is i got alreaady huge solution for lot diffrent files not only .csv and not we got something which is csv but it is not - i mean we use XmlTextReader. In this case i am not sure but i think i can't use XmlTextReader right?

Comment: No, i dont think `XmlTextReader` will work.  Since the new file is not consistent with the others and not even consistent with *itself* I think you have to implement a new parser method.  Also see the edit I made.

Answer (score 0):

As described by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values):

> An official standard for the CSV file format does not exist, but RFC
>   4180 provides a de facto standard for many aspects of it. In popular
>   usage, however, the term CSV may denote some closely related
>   delimiter-separated formats, **which use a variety of different field
>   delimiters. These include tab-separated values and space-separated
>   values, both of which are popular**. Such files are often even given a
>   .csv extension, despite the use of a different field separator than
>   the comma. This loose terminology creates problems for data exchange.

So, while it contains no comma's the space-separated values seem to be acceptable by it's definition

Comment: yes but to parse it you would need to develop your own parser as in this case let's say by TextFieldParser you are not able to parse either as delimeter or fixed as file is not delimeted by specified separator nor got fixed width. Is that correct?

Comment: This depends on what your csv-parser supports. It seems this file is delimited by spaces, so you might be able to parse it anyway

Comment: by spaces but for one of column you have double space, if this would be one space as well as rest xmltextreadercould do the job. Only way i see is custom parser e.g according to @user3697824 example